# Just want my JSON data using RestKit .20.3 without using a UITableView / NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: iphone, restkit-0.20

I have followed several tutorials that use the NSFetchedResultsController class to retrieve and display data to show in a UITableView.  What if I simply want to display pieces of my JSON result set in a text box on a simple UIViewController?  Does anyone have an example how to do this?  Below is a snippet of my code;

```
// Request Object with json paramaters
RequestInquiry *requestInquiry = [[RequestInquiry alloc] init];
requestInquiry.docType = @"T";
//requestInquiry.documentNum = @"999999999";
requestInquiry.documentNum = self.strTicketNum;
requestInquiry.clientAccount = @"6";
requestInquiry.clientCode = @"02";
requestInquiry.token = @"f1234XFASF43434";
requestInquiry.requestType = @"submit";
requestInquiry.userId = @"XXXX";
requestInquiry.class1 = @"class com.rest.client.JsonRequest";


[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:requestInquiry path:@"/RestIVR/restservices/ticketservices/jinquiry" parameters:nil success:nil failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);

}];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)callRemoteServiceWithPath: (NSString *)path postObject: (id)object andParameters: (NSString *)params withBlock:(void (^)(id ))block {
RKObjectManager *manager = [[MFRestKit sharedDataManager] objectManager];
NSData *postData  = [params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:baseUrl];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path relativeToURL:url]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

[AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager].enabled = YES;
RKManagedObjectRequestOperation *operation = [manager managedObjectRequestOperationWithRequest:request managedObjectContext:manager.managedObjectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation1, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
     block ([mappingResult array]);

} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation1, NSError *error) {
    RKLogDebug(@"Failure %@",error.debugDescription);
    block (error);
}];
[manager enqueueObjectRequestOperation:operation];
}
```

Comment: Excellent and much appreciated answer.  The thing I did not realize until you posted your answer was that mappingResult is actually an array.  So I created an object array and set it to mappingResult array like so; ticketParentArray = [mappingResult array];
         TicketParent *ticketParent = [ticketParentArray objectAtIndex:0];
         txtTicketNum.text = ticketParent.mvNumber;
And I am now able to access my JSON data elements without using NSFetchedResultsController.  Thanks again for your very helpful response.